# Why doesn't Google Drive show up in the list of apps when sharing a photo?

Tags: iphone, sharing, google-apps

1. Open the Photos app
2. Select an image
3. Pull up the menu (bottom left icon)
4. Available apps are Message, Mail, Twitter, etc.

Google Drive does not show up in that list (which seems to be called "Activities").

I have signed in to the Google Drive app and even restarted my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers above are old we are at iOS 10.  Google Drive did show and now it has disappeared just after successfully uploading from Photos to my Google Drive.

I'm signed in and can see my drive contents.

Comment: I had to close and restart both apps.  now working.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same issue here in August 2018 on iOS 11.4.  I am using the Apple-native Photos app and installed Google Drive two days ago, when I successfully was able to share from the Photos app onto Google Drive.  Now, two days later, it isn't working.  I tried the Save to Files option but Google Drive doesn't show up there either.

Turns out, it appears that I have selected too many photos at one time to upload.  When I select ten or fewer photos to share, it shows the Google Drive icon in the Activities list as an option.  But when I select more than ten photos, the Google Drive icon disappears from the Activities list.  Must be some kind of internal limit placed on it or perhaps a total upload size limit.  So if I want to upload more than ten photos, I will just do more than one upload.

Comment: Thank you - this solved the issue for me. There was absolutely no indication as to what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

It's a pain, can't be done at this time, but you CAN go through the Drive APP and select + and Upload Video and Images option to do about the same, but its not as intuitive / easy I agree.

Answer (score 1):

For Google Drive to show in an extensions list, the app must have been updated to support these extensions in iOS 8. It would appear at this time that the app has not been updated to support this.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that Google forgot to add this feature to their app

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Extensions are a relatively new addition to iOS and *most* apps are not updated to take advantage of this.

Comment: I see. But still, iOS 8 didn’t fall from the sky, there was a beta. Google should have prepared app updates for the launch of iOS 8. It is incredible that users still aren't able to upload images to Drive from within the Photos app. (Unless, of course, I'm missing an alternative method - I *am* a brand new iPhone user.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the “Save to Files” option?

I just now had the same question as you, found this post, figured it must have been deprecated, figured I’d give “files” a shot — found it there after the click. looks like thats where cloud & on disk storage options have been organized now.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this issue occurs only when using non-Apple apps and confirmed that Google Drive appears in the Activities menu when on Safari. To have access to every possible app in the Activities menu, you must use an Apple app (Photos, Safari, etc). Hope this helps.